# Array of structure pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I am running following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct point
{
   int formatbyte1;
   int formatbyte2;
   int formatbyte3;
};


const struct point SW_VERSN_POINT =
{
    1,2,3
};

const struct point SWMVERSN_POINT =
{
    4,5,6
};

const struct point *object_directory[] =
{
    &SW_VERSN_POINT,
    &SWMVERSN_POINT,
    0
};


int main()
{

    printf("%ld\n",  sizeof(SW_VERSN_POINT.formatbyte1));
    printf("%ld  0X%X, 0x%X\n", sizeof(struct point), &SWMVERSN_POINT.formatbyte1, &SW_VERSN_POINT.formatbyte1);
    printf("%ld  0X%X, 0x%X\n", sizeof(object_directory), object_directory[0], object_directory[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

The output of above program is

```
4
12  0XE2BF0788, 0xE2BF0778
24  0XE2BF0778, 0xE2BF0788
```

But when I modified the object_directory, removed 0 from it

```
const struct point *object_directory[] =
{
    &SW_VERSN_POINT,
    &SWMVERSN_POINT
};
```

Now output of above program is

```
4
12  0XF967D788, 0xF967D778
16  0XF967D778, 0xF967D788
```

Why is the size of object_directory is changes from 24 to 16. (How does 16 come from)
Thanks in advance.

This code is running on Linux.

Comment: Were you expecting a shorter array to take the *same* amount of space as a longer one?

Comment: By the way, `%X` is for printing `unsigned int`, not pointers. Format and data mismatch in `printf()` series invokes *undefined behavior*. To print pointers via `printf()` series, you should cast them to `void*` and use `%p`.